# Connect on a fixed point of a shape without connection points

Tags: mxgraph

I am using **mxGraph** javascript library. When dragging a connector from one shape to another I want the connector to remain connected in a fixed point on the target. 
 How can I do this **without** using connection points?
 This is implemented on draw.io (when dragging a connector over a target, this gets a green border; releasing the mouse click - sets the connector in that point, where it remains no mater where you move the target shape)
[hovering over a target shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyReJ.png)
[moved target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxWdm.png)

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set Style of Edge:

use `entryX` and `entryY` parameters to connect edge to shape on fixed point.

ex:

```
entryX=0.25;entryY=0.5;

var shapeA = graph.insertVertex(graph.getDefaultParent(), null, '', 10, 10, 50, 50, ''); 
var shapeB = graph.insertVertex(graph.getDefaultParent(), null, '', 100, 100, 50, 50, '');
var edge1 = graph.insertEdge(graph.getDefaultParent(), null, '', shapeA, shapeB, 'entryX=0.5;entryY=0.5;');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have tried it out, but it's not exactly what I need. For example, when moving the connector on another point on shapeB, that exact point is not remembered; therefore if I now move shapeB around the graph, the connector changes its connection point on shapeB. Do you perhaps know of a property that has to be set on the graph or shapes in general?